# Fluid width Son of Suckerfish dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, suckerfish

For CSS dropdown menus, I usually stick with the [Son of Suckerfish](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) dropdowns.  The technique works extremely well, but there's one small thing that's always bothered me:  the width of the dropdown links is always fixed.

Are there any ways to automatically resize the width of the items in a Suckerfish dropdown menu?  If not, are there any other CSS-based dropdown menu strategies that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `li` elements are `float`ed inside the `ul` element, they need to have a set width that is equal to the `ul` element. Otherwise, they will all be on the same line. The fixed width forces each one to jump to the next line.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhguL/3/

If you want, you can use jQuery or just plain JavaScript to calculate the width of the longest menu item in each `ul` and set each `li` and the `ul`'s widths to this this value.

Comment: I figured that would be a solution, but I was hoping to avoid JavaScript if I could.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. If you set the secondary list items to clear left, then they will stack on top of each other.

The problem there however is that if you want to change the background color on hover you have to set a fixed width, or else you'll have list items of varying widths.

But if you don't have to change the BG color, it's a nice way to do it and keep things fluid.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page, it helped me out.
You can do it without using js.
http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/dropdown-all-fluid.htm